# I'm trying to search multiple directories with hundreds of different text files with random text in them, but I'm struggling

Tags: python, search, os.walk

I have hundreds of little text files in multiple folders. In each text file is loads of random letters and symbols and I have been tasked with finding certain information like "HSBC" and "91274163" and others. I am very new to coding and I am struggling quite a lot, I do not have long left to complete this so if anyone can help I'd appreciated

```
import os
FILENAMES=[]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"****MY PATH****"):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".txt"):

            FILENAMES.append(filename)
            print(filename)

print('\n')
```

This is the first part of my code, Which displays all the text files and then exits.

```
for FILENAME in FILENAMES:
    print(FILENAME," contains the following function:\n")
    f1=open(FILENAME,'r')
    for line in f1:
        if ("HSBC") in line:
            print(line)
        else:
            pass
    print('\n')
    f1.close()
```

As soon as I add this part of the code I get "

```
f1=open(FILENAME,'r')
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'File-06Ijg.txt'
```

I have tried many other scripts, I encounter various different encoding errors etc. At least with this script I can display all the text files so im trying to figure this one out

Comment: you are not using the complete path for file , use root to compose the path and then open it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sorry, should've tested before answering. Shouldn't be `os.path.join(dirs, filename)` but `os.path.join(root, filename)` instead.

Try this:

```
import os
FILENAMES=[]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"****MY PATH****"):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".txt"):
            FILENAMES.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
            print(filename)

print('\n')

for FILENAME in FILENAMES:
    print(FILENAME," contains the following function:\n")
    with open(FILENAME,'r', encoding="utf-8") as f1:
        for line in f1:
            if "HSBC" in line:
                print(line)
    print('\n')
```

Edit: Typo, os.join -> os.path.join

Comment: Hello, thanks for your quick comment I appreciate it. 
I tried your new code and received 
FILENAMES.append(os.path.join(dirs, filename))
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen ntpath>", line 104, in join
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Comment: @Dylan1276 Updated, very sorry, as stated didn't test before answering, so lots of bad memory on my side.

Comment: No problem at all I appreciate the help, that works but I'm getting an encoding error: 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 494: character maps to <undefined>
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Dylan1276 You need to post the full traceback it will show you what line the error occurs.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    for line in f1:
  File "\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 494: character maps to <undefined>

This is the full traceback error

Comment: return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]

Answer (score 0):

add the changes in your first function

```
import os
FILENAMES=[]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"****MY PATH****"):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".txt"):
            # this line with get complete path
            file_path = os.path.join(root,filename)
            FILENAMES.append(file_path)
            print(file_path)

print('\n')
```